# Koa: How to get cookie's expiry date

Tags: node.js, cookies, koa

I've setup a cookie with `ctx.cookie.set('jwt', 'abcd', { expires: new Date(xxx) })`, but now I need to grab that cookie again and get it's expiry date, how can I do that?

All the options I can see for `ctx.cookie.get('jwt')` only get the value of the cookie, not any of its options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to view the expiration date of a cookie. It simply will not exist in the cookies collection once it has expired. If you truly require the specific date of expiration, you could store it in a separate cookie.